# Select A with min(C) if duplicate B else A

Tags: sql, sqlite

Terrible title I know...sorry it is the best I could come up with.

So given table class_members with the following data

```
class   member  id
alpha   foo     2
alpha   bar     2
beta    foo     1
beta    cat     1
gamma   x   3
gamma   y   3
```

I want to select all classes, but only the one with min(id) if a duplicate member is found.  Since foo is in both alpha and beta I want beta since its id is smaller.  I also want gamma since it has no members in common with alpha or beta.

Desired rows:

```
beta
gamma
```

I can determine that foo is a duplicate member, but I'm having trouble with the rest of the query.  The following is wrong, but it's what I've got so far.  I'm not sure how to combine the min check.  Do I need a case or am I completely over thinking things?

```
select class from class_members 
  where member not in 
  (
    select member from class_members group by member
    having count(member) > 1
  )
```

I'm using sqlite.
Here is a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/86ed6/12

Comment: If you want all classes, why don't you want alpha?

Comment: I want all classes unless there is a duplicate member

Comment: Not a complete solution, but maybe enough to give you some ideas - would it be useful to make a select of class, count(member), min(id), into a temporary table. This way you could single out the classes, and make some combinations from that. Not sure if you have to do all in one query, of you have some kind of programming language behind it all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery for a simpler statement:

```
with l as (select m.member, min(m.id) i from class_members m group by m.member)
select distinct m.class from class_members m where not exists 
    (select 1 from class_members m2 
     join l l1 on m2.member = l1.member 
     where l1.i < m.id and m2.class = m.class
);
```

Output:

| class |
| --- |
| beta |
| gamma |

Comment: After retesting this morning the answer I had accepted returned the wrong answer.  This is nice and concise and works.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're looking for something like that:

```
with d_classes as (
  select distinct class
  from class_members
  where member in (
    select member
    from class_members
    group by member
    having count(distinct class) > 1
  )
)

select distinct class
from class_members as a
where class in (select class from d_classes) and
id = (
  select min(b.id)
  from class_members as b
  where b.member in (
    select member
    from class_members as c
    where c.class = a.class
  )
)

union all

select distinct class
from class_members
where class not in (select class from d_classes)
```

so, it has multiple parts:

1. `with` select all classes which has duplicate members
2. first `union` select classes which are duplicates and has minimal id among classes with same members
3. second `union` just select all classes without duplicates

There are several edge cases which is not very clear how to handle, so leaving them to you:

- What if multiple classes have the same id, for example alpha/beta - both have 1
- What if 3 classes have similar members, like 1 (a,b) 2 (b,c) 3 (c,d) - from you logic it looks like you should pick `1 between 1 and 2` and `2 between 2 and 3`, right?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get this to work.  I went with the @sTTu version for its brevity.  You do raise some interesting cases.  In my real data the id is a timestamp, so the duplicate issue there is not a problem (my fault for oversimplifying the sample).  The 3 classes case seems possible, but probably rare (I'll have to watch for that).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select class
from class_members m
left join (
  select member, min(id) id
    from class_members 
    group by member
  having count(*) > 1
)x on x.member=m.member
where x.id=m.id or x.member is not null
```

Comment: I really like the conciseness of this query.  I don't think I would have ever gotten there.  Thanks!!!

Comment: I jumped the gun accepting this one...when I test it again this morning it returns alpha and beta vs beta and gamma.